# How to create a horizontal navigation in HTML/CSS above an image?

Tags: html, css, background, navigation

in my header I've got a large image. Above that image I want to place my navigation. 
The clue about it: The ul-Navigation-element got a gradient background. But if I hover an li-Navigation-Link I would like to display the underlying image! (Hope that's clear? Otherwise I'll do some photoshop to demonstrate) This should be flexible, meaning not to give each li-Element a specific snippet form the backgroundimage.

I would prefer a JS-solution instead of a messy markup. But I appreciate every possible idea you have on your mind. Maybe I'm just overlooking the most obvious and easy solution..

Best regards (:

Here is an image of what I tried to descripe. Hope it helps:
http://s7.directupload.net/images/110226/pv4v4c5r.jpg

Comment: example image would help, not sure I understand.  I assume you mean the navigation overlays the image, and not just that the navigation is above (vertically) on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem with javascript/jquery. It can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/QwJKY/.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for JS to do this, simply make it so that when you hover over the li-Navigation-Link, the element doesn't have a background attribute set.

This will create the 'transparency' that you want to achieve.

Comment: Guess my description isn't good enough. It's quite difficult for me to describe it in english.
I want the ul to fill the whole screen with a gradient! So the li should hide the ul-background on its position when hovering it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `background:transparent` for `a:hover`. This will show the background.

(for internet explorer you could use  `filter:alpha(opacity=100)` );

**Here an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3C9sZ/2/

Comment: What a usefull website. Thanks for that (; But how could I add that gradient you gave the li's to the rest of the bar? It should fill the whole page horizontally. In addition I need that gradient on the left of the li's too because it shouldn't be positioned at the very left.